# worker showing offline in nanopool my rig shows it is hashing. Need help please!

Tags: mining-pools

I am using nanopool and it did work after initial start up. I rebooted the rig and now my worker is offline. I am hashing and connected ot pool1 us-pool pool2 eu-pool. 
Has anyone else had this problem? 
Please help and thank you in advance for any assistenace.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. Glad to hear I'm not alone but still curious what is going on. Are you using SMOS or Windows for mining? I have a rig on Windows and rig on SMOS and both show offline but are hashing fine.

I do have a rig that has been running for weeks just fine and today it shows it has rebooted 5 times. I wonder if nanopool is having issues or something.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. After running nicely for days (ubuntu) now my worker it show as offline on nanopool. However n. of shares found is increasing (hashing as normal) but last share submitted it shows as hours ago. Could be that there is problem with the pool or possibly anything else?

Answer (score 0):

ive had the same problem for the past 5 hours. was worried it ws only me but i suppose others are having the same problem. could be a nanopool back end issue.
hope they resolve it soon for us. nanopool has been acting up a bit in recent time and i hope its not something permanent with them as theyve been quite good.